# How to copy a group setting for further modification?

Tags: django, django-admin

I am working on a Django website and I have extended the Django group model in admin page. Now when adding a new group, the user has to edit a list of settings. I am wondering if there is a way for user to select and copy a current group setting, then modify it into a new group. Does anyone have suggestions?